# how to set a default value in radiobutton list using data table

Tags: asp.net

i have  a  radiobuton list in which i am  binding to my datat table. I am  able  to  bind  to a radiobuttonlist
 I have the  column **[id, name]**
  by  deafult  **name**  should  get selected  in radio button list .

1. now by  default I need to select one radiobutton for the value in datatable
   how  to   achive this  concept  here
   thank you

Answer (score 11):

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Two</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get an item by name or value :

```
radiobuttonlist.Items.FindByValue("your_items_value").Selected = true;
// or by it's text : 
// radiobuttonlist.Items.FindByText("your_items_text").Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
  radiobuttonlist.SelectedIndex=1;//the index of items in radiobutton in the list you want to select
```

If you want to Select by Text then try

```
radiobuttonlist.Items.FindByText("yourtext").Selected = true;
```

If u want to select by value then try

```
  radiobuttonlist.SelectedValue = "12";
```

Comment: how to do same but only when user open page first time if user already works with it  it should not go to first index